# Persisting Session Storage

Tags: javascript, html, json, session

I need to persist the login status in sessionStorage but I cant seem to get it to work, can someone help me edit the sessionstorage code to make this work?

Below is my code with the session storage script that I'm trying to make work.

```html
<head>

        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=yes, initialscale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="logincss.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="loginjavascript.js"></script>

        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('#form').submit(function (event) {
                    $.post(this.action, $(this).serialize(), function (data) {
                        alert(data.msg+"  "+data.status);
                        $('#status').html(data.msg);
                        if (data.status==1){
                            $('#hide').toggle();
                            //'Sessionstorage here'
                            $('login').click(function () {
                                var name = this.name;
                                var info = 'div#' + name;
                                if ($(info).is(':hidden')) {
                                    if (sessionStorage[name]) {
                                        var obj = JSON.parse(sessionStorage[name]);
                                        var div = 'div#' + obj.pid;
                                        $(div).html(item({product: obj}));
                                    }
                                }
                                $(info).toggle();
                                return false;
                            });
                        }
                    }, 'json');
                    event.preventDefault();
                });
            });
           
        </script>  
        
    </head>

    <header class="cf">
        <img src="images/badnoise.png" alt="logo" width="199" height="92">  
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li id="login">
                    <div id="status">Not logged in</div>
                    <a id="login-trigger" href="#">
                        Log in <span>&#x25BC;</span>
                    </a>
                    <div id="login-content">
                            <form id="form" action="login.php">
                                <fieldset id="inputs">
                                    <input id="username" type="email" name="Email" value="bard@stratford.com" placeholder="Your email address" required />   
                                    <input id="password" type="password" name="Password" value="Hamlet34" placeholder="Password" required /><br/>
                                    Password contains at least 1 capital letter. <br/>
                                    Password contains at least 5 lower case letters. <br/>
                                    Password contains at least 1 number.<br/>
                                    Password must be a minimum of 8 characters.
                                </fieldset>
                                <fieldset id="actions">
                                    <input type="submit" id="submit1" value="Log in">
                                    <label><input type="checkbox" checked="checked"> Keep me signed in</label>
                                </fieldset>
                            </form>
                    </div><br/>                  
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <center><h1><a href="index.php">Artists<a>    ||     <a href="songs.php">Songs</a></h1></center><h1>
                            </header>
```

Thank you

Comment: Tell us a clear problem statement. What's the problem? Have you got errors in console?

Comment: Persist in which way? You haven't described where it is getting lost. Note that session storage is for sessions. At the end of a session, you can expect it to be gone by design. If you want some sort of persistent local storage, use the localStorage API.

Comment: @GregPettit you're right, but I think is a misspelling, when he said "persistent" I think he want to say "store", so he needs store info in session, but he can't. First of all, I don't see the initialization of `sessionStorage`.

Comment: Yes so I need to keep the status as 'LOGGED IN' on all pages...

Comment: I agree that the code is a bit unclear. 
Are you aware that in sessionStorage you can't place an object or an array? its just a key value pair where the value is a string or a number?